# how to make wsdl that doesn't need to be changed when things change?

Tags: xml, web-services, interface, wsdl, xsd

I'm making a CRUD Web Service and I have objects (which are also database records in my system) let's say customer with dozens of attibutes. Some of the attributes can change during the years. In rare occasion they can be renamed which i think is not a problem because that's inner implementation and the attribte names are not needed to be in the interface. However there will be new attributes and i don't know how to handle them correctly.

What I was planning to do is like this in schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="tKeyValuePair">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="fieldname" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="keyvaluepair" type="tKeyValuePair"  />

<xs:complexType name="tKeyValuePairs">
 <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="keyvaluepair" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="fieldvalues" type="tKeyValuePairs" /> 

<xs:complexType name="tCustomerBase">
 <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="customername" type="xs:string" />
   <!-- here are other fields that can't change but can be minOccurs="0"-->
  <xs:element ref="fieldvalues"  />
</xs:sequence>
```

Then I have a type for each operation that extends tCustomerBase like adding customerid in tCustomerUpdate for update to acts as key to find correct customer, adding createuser in tCustomerCreate for insert to store who created it in an other system.

Now the fieldvalues are strings and i know that which field should be of which type and i can convert them before db-operation in my WS.

But does this make sense? Should I use

```
xsd:any
```

somehow for the rest of the fields?

What about using

```
xsd:anyType
```

Could I use that instead of string as type for keyvalue pair's value? I would appreciate help how really to do this right!

Besides my question i will be happy to hear any comments about this kinda schema design. So feel free to comment the part of mock-up schema i wrote here!

Thanks and Best Reagards -Matti

Comment: Implement your operations to accept simple xml string argument as the only parameter, that you'll then convert to objects yourself in code using `JAXB`. This way, if the interface requirements change in terms of just the arguments, all you need to do is advise your web service clients accordingly. The wsdl won't need to change unless you're adding/removing an operation.

Comment: thanks for your answer! jaxb seems to be equivalent of xsd.exe. i understand that if it's simple string it doesn't have to change.... but really? that interface doesn't document anything and thus kind of violates the wsdl-interface's idea. maybe it's good for ever-changing interface. but here it seems like an overkill. i might be wrong. also i don't know how to convert simple string to an object. i thought it would convert it to java.lang.String and that's it.